# Animating a multiple sprite without animator in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

So I have this multiple sprite in which there are eight sprites. I want to show them to the player one by one with say 0.5 second delay, like an animation. I can easily do it using animation and animator and stuff in Unity, but I want to do it without that option, and only using code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the Sprites in memory somewhere, and update the SpriteRenderer every frame with the new Sprite that you want to use with a Sprite from memory.